# Can lambda capture a pointer to a method?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

How can one create a lambda capturing a pointer to a method in C++11? If I try to do so using the GCC (4.6) compiler, it cannot deduce the expression type.

I tried this:

```
typedef std::string ( Class::*pointerName ) () const;
pointerName = &Class::method;

auto comparer = [&pointerName] ( Class * pFirst, Class * pSecond )
{
   return ( pFirst->*pointerName ) () < ( pSecond->*pointerName ) ();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used the typedef'd `pointerName` as a variable and not as a type (or simply forgot to name the variable):

```
typedef std::string ( Class::*pointerName ) () const; // declares a type alias
pointerName ptr = &Class::method;
//          ^^^ a name for your variable of type pointerName

auto comparer = [&ptr] ( Class * pFirst, Class * pSecond )
{
    return ( pFirst->*ptr ) () < ( pSecond->*ptr ) ();
}
```

(or just drop the `typedef` in your original code)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef void (*func_t)(void);
typedef void (*function)(func_t f);

void foo()
{
    std::cout<<"Foo";
}

int main() {

    function func = [&](func_t f) {
        f();
    };

    func(&foo);

    return 0;
}
```